# Ubuntu 11.10 не загружается

Tags: grub, ubuntu

Установил ubuntu 11.10 на отдельный раздел. При установке выделил место для grub (ext4) "/boot" в том же разделе, под swap и под саму систему "/". После установки и перезагрузки как обычно грузится windows. Что-нибудь тут можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить так: Partition Magic`ом установить раздел с grub в режим "загрузочный". [Читаем тут](http://pingvinoff.net/2008/09/08/vista-i-ubuntu-na-odnom-kompe/); [и тут](http://otvety.google.ru/otvety/thread?tid=4d0994ee92e3ca52&pli=1). Grub надо было ставить в MBR (master boot record), он бы сам обнаружил винду и сделал для нее загрузочную запись, обычно под названием Other.

Comment: а как ставить grub в MBR? Это как-то при разметке диска можно сделать?

Comment: Во время инсталляции - инсталлятор спршивает куда ставить grub. Это обычно уже после разметки диска.

Answer (score 0):

Grub можно установить загрузившись с live cd и выполнив команду grub-install /устройство/на которое/ставить  например /dev/sda